# RoR not creating nested record on before_save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-1.9.2

I have a model Site which has_many photos.

In site model I have

```
before_save :defaults
def defaults
    if self.photos.length ==0 && !SiteDefault.default_photo.nil?
      photo = Photo.new 
      photo.image = SiteDefault.default_photo.image
      self.photos.push photo  
    end 
end
```

It is not storing the default photo when creating a site. Why?

I dont see any error in the console. The image is being uploaded to Amazon S3 correctly.

Comment: why do you want to have tons of identical photos stored on your drive ? why not check in your views if a site has a photo, and display a default one if not ?

Comment: so the photo record isn't being saved at all, or is it saved but no association with the site?

Comment: I solved it by changing to after_create event.

Comment: It was not being saved at all. I dont know why